# Intel Wireless-AC 9560 Slow on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu 18.04.

While I was able to get download speeds of up to 2 Mbps in Windows, on Ubuntu I struggle to even hit 110 Kbps.

I have my phone next to the computer tethering internet to my computer from that same network, and I get the same 2 Mbps bandwidth.

Any advice on how to fix this?
Here's the output from **lshw -C network**:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 18:1d:ea:d5:d8:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.0.0-23-generic firmware=43.95eb4e97.0 ip=[redacted] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:8451c000-8451ffff
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a different Intel Wifi product, I found disabling power management on the device remedied a batch of anomalous events ... perhaps it will work here.

Here's how I did it:

Create: `/etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`
Enable: `chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/wifi-powerman-off`

Replace **interface name**

```
#!/bin/sh

IWCONFIG=/sbin/iwconfig
WLAN_IFACE=<<interface name>>

if [ ! -x $IWCONFIG ]; then
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$IFACE" = $WLAN_IFACE ]; then
    $IWCONFIG $IFACE power off
fi
```